# jQuery Validation + Submit via $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Hello!*

My problem is the **following**:

The validation plugin works fine for me, except I don't want the form to submit when it isn't still valid.

The fact is, it validates and displays the errors but it does the submit even if it isn't valid.

---

**Validate**

```
$("form#form-utilizadores").validate({
  rules:{
    nome:{
      required:true
    },
    utilizador:{
      required:true
    },
    password:{
      required:true
    },
    tipo:{
      required:true
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Submit**

```
$('form#form-utilizadores').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('submit/submit-utilizadores.php',data,function(data){
      alert((data=='sucesso') ? 'Adicionado com sucesso!' : data);
      top.location.reload();
    }
  );
});
```

---

Thanks for the time spent trying to help me! :)

Comment: Do you assign form.submit() _before_ assigning form.validate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the code you have in `$('form#form-utilizadores').submit()` and put it in the `submitHandler` parameter of the jQuery validate settings, try this:

```
$("form#form-utilizadores").validate({
    rules: {
        // your current rules...
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $(form).serialize();
        $.post(    
            'submit/submit-utilizadores.php',
            data,
            function(data) {
                alert((data=='sucesso') ? 'Adicionado com sucesso!' : data);
                top.location.reload();
            }
        );
    }
});
```

The reason your current code is always submitted, is because the form `submit` event is always raised, regardless of whether the form is valid or not. Going via the `submitHandler` lets jQuery validate control whether to post the form, depending on it's validity.

Comment: Ok, I found that the problem is that you need to do `$(form).serialize();` otherwise it will not work :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code in your submit handler:

```
$('form#form-utilizadores').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).valid() == false){
        return;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and another way of doing it, but I guess Rory's answer is the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Return false from submit if your validation fails.